# Inverting image intensities in c

Tags: arrays, c, colors

```
void invert( uint8_t array[], 
         unsigned int cols, 
         unsigned int rows )
{
    int y;
    uint8_t darkest = 255;
    uint8_t lightest = 0;
    uint8_t anygray = y;
    for (int x = 0; x < (cols*rows); x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < (cols*rows); y++)
        {
            if (array[x] == darkest && array[x] == anygray && array[x] == lightest)
            {
                array[x] = 255-y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a function here that inverts the image intensities, so that black becomes white, and vice versa as well as all the light grays become dark grays.  But my code here doesn't seem to work and I don't know where i went wrong.  Would anybody be able to help me out?

Comment: What is the inner loop for? Also, what has the counter `y` to do with image intensity? Invert the pixels one at a time, using only the value of the current pixel. There isn't any condition attached to the reversal, either.

Comment: (I like how the variable `anygray` is appropriately named. `y` isn't initialised, so `anygray` can literally be any gray.)

Comment: @MOehm I initially thought that y can be any any gray.  I also put two loops so it can loop over rows and columns.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit snarky there. But the way your data is organised (namely in one linear array) you only need one loop, which visits all pixels. Then you just reverse the intensity unconditionally: After you have visited it, every pixel is `new == 255 - old`. I think you were overthinking things in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't prototyped anything to check but I see at least two things that look suspicious.

1) I expected the && in the IF to be ||.

2) I expected array[x] = 255 - y to be something like array[x] = 255 - array[x].

Comment: so that means I won't even need y right?  But how would I account for gray if I don't add y?

Comment: You account for the grey by using the value that is already there, `array[x]`, just as Keith suggested in (2). You can see that your inner loop is pointless, because you are constantly overwriting the same pixel. Also, `y` can take values greater than 255 in your loop, depending on the dimensions of your image. (That doesn't hurt, but will not give you the results you want.)

Comment: "y" appears to be related to position, not to the color in a position. array appears to be holding the colors.